# MySql: How to group by day and by hour each?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

What I am trying to do is a query that brings me all the count of records each hour by day. See example in table below:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Day/Hour</th>
    <th>0</th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
    <th>6</th>
    <th>7</th>
    <th>8</th>
    <th>9</th>
    <th>10</th>
    <th>11</th>
    <th>12</th>
    <th>13</th>
    <th>14</th>
    <th>15</th>
    <th>16</th>
    <th>17</th>
    <th>18</th>
    <th>19</th>
    <th>20</th>
    <th>21</th>
    <th>22</th>
    <th>23</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2015-06-02</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>198</td>
    <td>234</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>198</td>
    <td>234</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>198</td>
    <td>234</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>198</td>
    <td>234</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>198</td>
    <td>234</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>198</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2015-06-01</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>342</td>
    <td>1348</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>342</td>
    <td>1348</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>342</td>
    <td>1348</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>342</td>
    <td>1348</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>342</td>
    <td>1348</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>342</td>
    <td>1348</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Actually, that is exactly how I should be displaying the data (the table), also how I need the resulset.

Comment: Where is your MySQL code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the hours in a day are a constant set that will not change any time in the foreseeable future, and since you probably want to display day-hour combinations with no rows too, the easiest thing may just be to have 24 columns hardcoded in your query:

```
SELECT   DATE(date_col),
         COUNT (CASE HOUR(date_col) WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "0",
         COUNT (CASE HOUR(date_col) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "1",
         -- 22 more of these
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY DATE(date_col)
```

Comment: Hey @Mureinik, thanks a lot for your answer. I kinda though that it was not possible "naturally". I tested your example and I am getting an error with the COUNT function, I must admit I do not quite understand the example. I tested it for the first 10 hours as follows:

Comment: @mkmnstr two things: First, I botched the `else` clauses - fixed now. Second - can to share the error?

Comment: yeah, here's the error: Error Code: 1630. FUNCTION records_v3.COUNT does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Comment: Hey @Mureinik, solved, was just the caps and the space between the count and the condition, thanks alot, this solved!! I cannot mark as correct! :(